# How can I tell a .NET DLL to reference a different version of another DLL?

Tags: .net, strongname

Our application uses a 3rd party library I'll call LotsOfStuff-7.5.0.2.dll. A commercial library we use is built so it references LotsOfStuff-7.5.0.1.dll. The difference between 7.5.0.2 and 7.5.0.1 is the code in a single method. The public signature of the one changed class is identical. All other classes are identical.

Is there a way we can tell the CommercialLibrary.dll that it's reference to LotsOfStuff-7.5.0.1.dll should instead be to LotsOfStuff-7.5.0.2.dll?

All DLLs are strongly named and we don't have the key to CommercialLibrary.dll so editing the DLL is out.

CommercialLibrary.dll we directly reference. LotsOfStuff-7.5.0.2.dll we get from NuGet. Neither is in the GAC.

Can this be done? If so, how?

Comment: Surely you heard of bindingRedirect before?  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/redirect-assembly-versions

Comment: @HansPassant No i hadn't - thank you.

Comment: @HansPassant - It appears to be ok when it is built with 7.5.0.1 and we're using 7.5.0.2 even without binding redirect. Is that unexpected?

Comment: Not really, MSBuild normally knows how to detect this and auto-generates the bindingRedirect.  Look in the generated yourapp.exe.config file.